# Deriviate of Van der Waals equation

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, physics

Van der Waals equation:
$$p=\frac{R T}{v-b}-\frac{a}{v^2}$$

I need to calculate $$k_T=-\frac{1}{v}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial p}\right)_T$$

Also we know: $$p_c=\frac{a}{27b^2},~v_c=3b,~T_c=\frac{8a}{27bR}$$

So,  $$\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial v}\right)_T=-~\frac{R T}{(v-b)^2}+2\frac{a}{v^3}$$

At $V=V_c$:

$$-~\frac{R T}{(v-b)^2}+2\frac{a}{v^3}=-~\frac{R(T-T_c)}{4b^2}$$

Hence:

$$k_T(T,v=v_c)=-~\frac{1}{v}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial p}\right)_T\approx C(T-T_c)^{-\gamma}$$

But I cant calculate $k_T(T=T_c,p)$.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying your notation? What does your subscript $T$ mean after your derivative? Is gamma arbitrary, just to show that $k_T$ is of a certain form, or should that be defined somewhere? You have $\frac{\partial v}{\partial p}$ in two of your three partial derivatives. Are you referring to solving the first line for $v$ and taking the derivative with respect to $p$, or are those mistakenly flipped?

Comment: @delkov Time has passed since I studied Thermodynamics. I was searching in the internet and found this article http://www.harding.edu/lmurray/themo_files/notes/ch04.pdf. Maybe it's what you are looking for. See page 10, formulas 4.67, 4.68 and 4.69.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asked to calculate the isothermal compressibility, i.e. $ \kappa_T=-\frac{1}{v}\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial p}\right)_T $.

You can use the fact that $ \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial p} \right)_T = \left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial v} \right)_T^{-1} $, i.e.

$$ \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial v}\right)_T = - \frac{R T}{(v-b)^2} + \frac{2a}{v^3} = - \frac{RTv^3}{(v-b)^2v^3} + \frac{2a(v-b)^2}{(v-b)^2v^3} = \frac{2a(v-b)^2 - RTv^3}{(v-b)^2v^3} $$

Substituting $ v = v_c = 3b $ into this equation, we get:

$$ \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial v}\right)_T = \frac{2a(v_c-b)^2 - RTv_c^3}{(v_c-b)^2{v_c}^3} = \frac{2a(4b^2) - RT(3b)^3}{(2b)^2(3b)^3} = \frac{b^2(8a - 27RTb)}{108b^5} = \frac{8a - 27RTb}{108b^3} $$

Therefore, we get:

$$ \kappa_T = - \frac{1}{v_c} \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial p}\right)_T = - \frac{1}{v_c} \left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial v} \right)_T^{-1} = - \frac{1}{3b} \times \frac{108b^3}{8a - 27RTb} = \frac{36b^2}{27RTb - 8a} $$